# jest test simulate 200

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Hi I need to test a login controller, but always will be 400 and I need to simulate a 200, but hosnestly I dont know how to do that, here my test:

```
test("JWT OK, status 200, remember false", async () => {


   const code = "code";
  const state = "state";
  const company = "comany";

  const response = await supertest(app)
    
     .get(`/auth/${company}`)
    .send({
      "state": state,
      "code": code
   
    }) 
  
  
});
```

and here my code controller login, which is call from (/auth/${company}`)

```
export class AuthService {
    public async Login(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response<any> | undefined> {
        try {
            const company: IAuth['company']  = req.params.company;
            const state : IAuth['state'] = req.query.state;
            const code : IAuth['code'] = req.query.code;  
          ....some code....
```

the problem is always is response.status 400 and I dont know how test for simulate status 200...

sorry i just started in this area..

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your `Login` function reads the `state, code` from the request's query. But, in your test, you send them as a request body. Then maybe the `state, code` be missing then the server throws 400.

Let's try

```
...
  const response = await supertest(app)
    .get(`/auth/${company}`)
    .query({ // query instead of send
      "state": state,
      "code": code
    }) 
...
```